# Weird implementation of tryAdvance in Spliterator.OfInt

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, spliterator

How does it work?
How can `Consumer<? super Integer>` be cast to `IntConsumer`??

```
default boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super Integer> action) {
    if (action instanceof IntConsumer) {
        return tryAdvance((IntConsumer) action);
    }
    else {
        if (Tripwire.ENABLED)
            Tripwire.trip(getClass(),
                      "{0} calling Spliterator.OfInt.tryAdvance((IntConsumer) action::accept)");
        return tryAdvance((IntConsumer) action::accept);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no reason why `action` can't implement both interfaces.

Comment: Yes, I had not thought about it. It seemed to me that this is some kind of magic ;)

Comment: Its simpler than that.  While `action` might not implement `IntConsumer`, that's not what the target of the cast is.  The target of the cast is the bound method reference `action::accept`, and the cast is providing a compatible target type for that method reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn’t quite clear as there are *two* type casts in the posted code.

The first one checks via `instanceof` whether the `Consumer<? super Integer>` also implements `IntConsumer` and does an ordinary type cast then, assuming that a class implementing `Consumer` and `IntConsumer` at the same time will do that with the same semantic. Compare with [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.OfInt.html#tryAdvance-java.util.function.Consumer-):

> **Implementation Requirements**:
>
> If the action is an instance of `IntConsumer` then it is cast to `IntConsumer` and passed to [`tryAdvance(java.util.function.IntConsumer);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.OfInt.html#tryAdvance-java.util.function.IntConsumer-) otherwise the action is adapted to an instance of `IntConsumer`, by boxing the argument of `IntConsumer`, and then passed to [`tryAdvance(java.util.function.IntConsumer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.OfInt.html#tryAdvance-java.util.function.IntConsumer-).

So the first `instanceof` check and type cast are the first part of the contract, avoiding boxing if the `action` argument implements both interfaces.

The second type cast is part of the described adaptation to a boxing `IntConsumer` whereas the boxing is implied by the [method reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) `(IntConsumer) action::accept`. This method reference refers to the method [`void accept(T t)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html#accept-T-) (where `T := ? super Integer`) which can be adapted to the function signature of `IntConsumer`, as [described by Brian Goetz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30954576/2711488). Since this functional signature does not only fulfill the signature of `IntConsumer` but also (of course) the signature of `Consumer<? super Integer>` the type cast is needed to disambiguate between the overloaded `tryAdvance` methods. It would be unnecessary when using the equivalent lambda expression

```
return tryAdvance((int i)->c.accept(i));
```

Answer (score 5):

The cast is providing a *target type* for the bound method reference `action::accept`, which is equivalent to the lambda `x -> action.accept(x)`.  The `IntConsumer` target type causes this lambda (which would prefer to accept an Integer) to be adapted to accept an int (which will cause the argument to be implicitly boxed before passing it to `action.accept()`).